# not able to read application.properties file in Spring boot Java

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, maven, graphql

I'm trying to make a class to post GraphQL API using java and maven spring boot project with VSCode on Windows.
I've encountered an error that It doesn't find any url that i link using @Value.

this is the error log

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)   
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Unable to parse url [] 
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
        Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below:       
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ? Request to POST  [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
                at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)   
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.reportThrowInSubscribe(Operators.java:232)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:71)        
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1711)
                at com.tarkov.randomweapongenerator.service.FetchAPI.SelectDataByWeaponId(FetchAPI.java:31)   
                at com.tarkov.randomweapongenerator.RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication.main(RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication.java:18)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
                at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
                at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
                at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:103)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1712)
                at com.tarkov.randomweapongenerator.service.FetchAPI.SelectDataByWeaponId(FetchAPI.java:31)   
                at com.tarkov.randomweapongenerator.RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication.main(RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication.java:18)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
                at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
                at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
                at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse url []
        at reactor.netty.http.client.UriEndpointFactory.createUriEndpoint(UriEndpointFactory.java:68)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.UriEndpointFactory.createUriEndpoint(UriEndpointFactory.java:44)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpClientHandler.<init>(HttpClientConnect.java:509)   
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:208)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1711)
        at com.tarkov.randomweapongenerator.service.FetchAPI.SelectDataByWeaponId(FetchAPI.java:31)
        at com.tarkov.randomweapongenerator.RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication.main(RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication.java:18)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)   
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

It tells that "Unable to parse url []" which means the url is empty.

this is my project tree.

```
├─.mvn
│  └─wrapper
├─src
│  ├─main
│  │  ├─java
│  │  │  └─com
│  │  │      └─tarkov
│  │  │          └─randomweapongenerator
│  │  │              ├─controller
│  │  │              ├─entity
│  │  │              ├─repository
│  │  │              └─service
│  │  └─resources
│  │      └─templates
│  └─test
│      └─java
│          └─com
│              └─tarkov
│                  └─randomweapongenerator
└─target
    ├─classes
    │  ├─com
    │  │  └─tarkov
    │  │      └─randomweapongenerator
    │  │          ├─controller
    │  │          ├─entity
    │  │          └─service
    │  └─templates
    ├─generated-sources
    │  └─annotations
    ├─generated-test-sources
    │  └─test-annotations
    ├─maven-archiver
    ├─maven-status
    │  └─maven-compiler-plugin
    │      ├─compile
    │      │  └─default-compile
    │      └─testCompile
    │          └─default-testCompile
    ├─surefire-reports
    └─test-classes
        └─com
            └─tarkov
                └─randomweapongenerator
```

This is a class i made to fetch API.

```
@Service
public class FetchAPI {

    @Value("${graphql.endpoint}")
    private String GraphQLurl;
    private WebClient webClient=WebClient.create();



    public void SelectDataByWeaponId(String id){
        String query="{\"query\" :\"{ items { name }}\"}";
        
        String response=webClient.post()
            .uri(GraphQLurl)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(query))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
        
        System.out.println(response);
    }

}
```

First time, I used `@Value("${graphql.endpoint}")` to link the API url in code.
So i searched a reason why and i found `@ComponentScan` that i have to use it to scan and add components into a container!

This is the code i added.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.tarkov.randomweapongenerator")
public class RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("hello");
        FetchAPI api=new FetchAPI();
        api.SelectDataByWeaponId("");
    }

}
```

In SelectDataByWeaponId, The argument doesn't need to fill. I don't use it in FetchAPI class for now.

I also made sure that i wrote the application.properties file right.
This is the endpoint url i set in application.properties.

`graphql.endpoint=https://api.tarkov.dev/graphql`

The file is also placed in right folder.

[image]

I build and excute the project with command "mvn clean install" and "java -jar result_file.jar".

Please tell me how to resolve it.. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring annotations such as `@Value` only work inside Spring beans, that are managed by Spring in the application context.

In your `main` method you are creating an instance of class `FetchAPI` yourself, outside of Spring:

```
FetchAPI api=new FetchAPI();
api.SelectDataByWeaponId("");
```

The object that the variable `api` refers to is not a bean managed by Spring, because you are instantiating it yourself using `new`. Spring annotations such as `@Value` are not processed when you do that, so that the member variable `GraphQLurl` in your object is `null`.

Don't instantiate classes that are intended to be Spring beans by using `new` directly. Instead, let Spring instantiate and manage them in the application context and use dependency injection (autowiring) when you need to use them.

What you can do is this:

First, remove the calls after `SpringApplication.run()` from your main application class. You can also remove the `@ComponentScan` annotation, because it does not make any difference in this case:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RandomWeaponGeneratorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Add a class that implements interface `CommandLineRunner` to your application, into which you autowire an instance of `FetchAPI` instead of creating it yourself with `new`:

```
@Component
public class RandomWeaponGeneratorRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private FetchAPI api;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        api.SelectDataByWeaponId("");
    }
}
```

Spring Boot will automatically instantiate and call the `run` method when it finds this class.

Comment: Thank you finally my cord works and i found a clue that i should learn before running this by your answer!

I found out the core concept is that DI, Annotation. I've studied these things and tried again with few annotations which are Value, Component, Autowired, CommandLineRunner. XD

Thank you so much! now i will find out what CommandLineRunner is haha.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you kinda combine Plain Java object creation with Spring(DI, IOC, etc).

You have to understand that processing of the **@Value** annotation is performed by a BeanPostProcessor which in your particular case means that you have to use DI to at least access the class where this value is initialised.

---

In another words, really simple. You can`t combine

```
new FetchAPI(); with @Value annotation
```

( actually there are some ways but this is not the case).

---

If you want to follow spring way but do something like console runner - You can use this code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication
    implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final FetchAPI fetchAPI; //Injection of your FetchAPI service bean using constructor

    @Autowired
    public SpringBootConsoleApplication(FetchAPI fetchAPI) {
        this.fetchAPI = fetchAPI;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        //call your singleton bean with already initiated @Value annotation inside
        fetchAPI.SelectDataByWeaponId("your ID");
    }
}
```